# Street View for Google Maps iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is street view available in the brand new Google Maps iOS SDK (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) ?

I looked at the framework code but it doesn't seem to provide such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they listened to you! Take a look at the release notes for v1.4
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_140_-_july_2013

Answer (score 2):

Streetview is not yet available in the iOS SDK. Please file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request) so show your interest in having the feature added.

Comment: An API is available from Google Maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) but no SDK yet. It would be a great open source project :)

Comment: Steet View has been added to version 1.4 - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_140_-_july_2013

Answer (score 0):

May be `MapKit API` for `iPhone` does not Provide features of Street View.

All This features That provide by [`MapKit API is here`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

In iOS 5.1 and earlier, the Map Kit framework uses the Google Mobile Maps (GMM) service to provide map data. Use of specific classes of this framework that may be provide street View.

The Google Street View Image API lets you embed a static (non-interactive) Street View panorama or thumbnail into your web page, without the use of JavaScript.

For more information [CheCk This LInk.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/)

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm talking about Google Maps SDK for iOS https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/